# The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: wcf

I try to solve this since few days ... I get this error only when call soap service, in rest all ok.

My config in client (in service is the same, only not have client section)

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="soap" binding="customHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyCustomHttpBinding" name="Soap" contract="ServiceModel.IService" />
</client>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="Service.svc" service="ServiceModel.Service" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="MyCustomHttpBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
      <context protectionLevel ="None"/>
      <httpTransport transferMode ="Buffered" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingSettings" closeTimeout="00:01:00" transferMode="Streamed" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="654321">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="ServiceModel.Service" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyCustomHttpBinding" name="Soap" contract="ServiceModel.IService" />
    <endpoint address="rest" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingSettings" name="Json" contract="ServiceModel.IService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://dev.add.com/Service.svc/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"  />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" helpEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

my service

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "ServiceModel")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke()]
    GetInfoResponse GetRestData(GetInfoRequest message);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke()]
    GetInfoResponse GetSoapData(GetInfoRequest message);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string Save(Stream message);
}
```

call service

```
            GetInfoRequest message = CheckedFields;
        string soap = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                <soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">
                  <soap12:Header>
                    <Action soap12:mustUnderstand=""1"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"">ServiceModel/IService/GetSoapData</Action>
                  </soap12:Header>
                <soap12:Body>
            <GetInfoRequest  xmlns=""ServiceModel"">
                <Data xmlns:d4p1=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""/>
            </GetInfoRequest>
            </soap12:Body>
            </soap12:Envelope>";
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetInfoRequest));
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://dev.add.renault.com/Service.svc/soap");
        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        serializer.Serialize(stream1, message);
        stream1.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
        string t = sr.ReadToEnd();
        t = t.Remove(0, 22).Trim();
        t = string.Format(soap, t);
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        request.Timeout = 99999999;
        request.ContentLength = t.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
        request.Accept = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";

        using (Stream stm = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
            {
                stmw.Write(t);
            }
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var abc = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Stack Trace

```
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.ThrowAndCatch(Exception e, Message message)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.ReplyFailure(RequestContext request, Message fault, String action, String reason, FaultCode code)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.ReplyFailure(RequestContext request, FaultCode code, String reason, String action)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.ReplyContractFilterDidNotMatch(RequestContext request)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.EnsureChannelAndEndpoint(RequestContext request)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.TryRetrievingInstanceContext(RequestContext request)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action callback)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that in config I use Soap12 but message which I send using WebHttpRequest contains Soap Header with non Soap12 element.

Answer (score 0):

The action you have hardcoded in your request string is wrong. The default action will probably be ServiceModel/IService1/GetSoapData.

[I would strongly recommend using a standard WCF client to test your SOAP service. You can turn diagnostics and log messages if you need to examine the actual XML generated. WCF provides lots of capabilities to control the messages it receives/sends. Unless you understand the implementation of all the configuration switches you are using it is very difficult to predict what message changes are required.]